# Font color v-select item cannot be changed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I use `.v-list-items__title` to change font color in select item but it cannot
be changed

```
     <v-select
        :items="dataOption"
        label="item"
        solo
        class="header-select"
        :dark="$colorMode.value === 'night'"
      ></v-select>
```

css

```
.v-list-items__title {
  color: #ffd54f;
}
```

Comment: try this `.v-select__selection--comma{
  color:#ffd54f !important;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [item slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#item) then you could define its style :

```
 <v-select
        :items="dataOption"
        label="item"
        solo
        class="header-select"
        :dark="$colorMode.value === 'night'"
#item="{item}"     
 >
<span style="color: #ffd54f;">{{item.label}}</span>
</v-select>
```